# Es posible customizar el index en un array.push()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo la siguiente duda, os pongo en antecendentes, tengo que realizar 2 consultas 1 para saber los la `entidad1` de un contrato y otra para saber la `entidad2` de cada contrato.

Por lo tanto, lo que consigo actualmente es un array de la siguiente manera

```
Array = [
  entidad1 : [
     entidad2, 
     entidad2, 
     entidad2
  ]
]
```

Es decir, un `array de varias entidad`1, y `cada una de estas contiene varias entidad2`

Esto trasladado a datos seria lo siguiente

```
Array = [
   0:[{id, nombre},{id, nombre},{id, nombre}]
   1:[{id, nombre}]
   2:[{id, nombre},{id, nombre}]
]
```

Mi duda viene en si se podría modificar el valor del `index` del objeto `entidad1` y que en vez de ser 0,1,2... pudiese ser una valor numérico dado por mi.

Comment: En vez de un array, puedes utilizar un objeto... `obj = {obj_x:[{id, nombre},{id, nombre},{id, nombre}], obj_y:[{id, nombre}], obj_z:[{id, nombre},{id, nombre}]}`

Comment: Se entiende que en ese caso, el equivalente al `push` sería `obj['obj_aa'] = [{id,nombre},{id,nombre}];`

Comment: A menos que OP no sepa lo que busca, lo que VFG dice es correcto. Por qué no lo redactas y lo completas como una respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes hacerlo en el constructor ni al declarar un array literal, pero sí puedes, por ejemplo:

**1.-** Desplazar el puntero del array, y seguir pusheando a partir de ese desplazamiento:

En ese ejemplo yo accedería al valor 'domingo' haciendo `miArray[6]`

```
  cost miArray = ['lunes','martes']
  miArray.length=6
  miArray.push('domingo');
 
  // ['lunes', 'martes', empty × 4, 'domingo']
```

Nótese que los índices vacíos no son lo mismo que tener nulls o undefined.

**2.-** Declarar el valor de un índice arbitrario. El array se redimensiona para llegar a ese índice, quedando vacíos los lugares intermedios

```
const miArray = ['lunes','martes']

miArray[30]='fin de mes'

// ['lunes', 'martes', empty × 28, 'fin de mes']
```